# Tratamento de Exeções na MODEL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, model

Como eu faço para mandar uma exeção do Model para View em forma de um Alert, por exemplo MODEL :

```
Try { 
    // codigo 

}catch{

    // Aqui quero tratar o erro e mandar uma mensagem pra ser exibida na view em forma de alerta.

}
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se achar um problema na model, você pode mandar um alert assim:

```
public ActionResult Create(ItemModel fvm){
   try
   {

   } 
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      TempData["msg"] = "<script>alert('Olá mundo');</script>";
   }
}

@Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
```

ou

```
return JavaScript(alert("Olá mundo"));
```

ou

```
return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Olá mundo');</script>");
```

Comment: É bem isso, ótima resposta !!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilziar o `AddModelError`. Com ele, não será exibido um alert com a mensagem de erro, mas o erro será exibido na tela igual tratamento de erro que são feitos em inputs.

Na sua controller:

```
Try { 
    // codigo 

}catch{

     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Coloque seu erro aqui.");
}
```

Na view, você utiliza `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` para o erro ser exibido.